# Can every d3 chard drawn by rickshaw for cloud-computing software platform?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I have included tags openstack and amazon-web-services because they are cloud-computing platform.

I am going to start Rickshaw chart. It's all based on d3 underneath, so graphs are drawn with standard SVG and styled with CSS.

I am working on [openstack](https://www.openstack.org/). It is a free and open-source **cloud-computing software platform**. This is alternative to Amazon Web Services. Openstack is in initial phase of development. For demonstration purpose they are using very simple chart like  bar-chart, pie-chart, line chart.

My Question that Is it possible to draw every [d3](http://d3js.org/) chart through [rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/).

In [Open-Stack](https://www.openstack.org/) project (like Amazon Web Services )
they are using d3 and rickshaw to draw very simple chart like pie chart, bar chart

Comment: Hello sir, I think this not the way that tags work. Tags have to be related to your problem in order to help people filter, find and answer your question. For example, (in your case) if I replicate your issue to my local development machine the problem will be the same. So it does not have to do with [tag:openstack] or [tag:amazon-web-services]. If you see what questions are under the [tag:openstack] tag, I think it will be more clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to draw every D3 chart through rickshaw?

No. Rickshaw is a graph library (focused on time series), whereas D3 is more of a framework, so it gives you much more functionality.